# Reviewer rejecting edits, only to make their own less useful edit

Tags: support, review-queues, rejected-edits

Recently, I made the following [edit request](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8406166). In my mind, this significantly improved the clarity of the question, but the edit was rejected, because "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed". Although I don't really agree, I accept that the edit was rejected.

However, immediately after rejecting my edit, the reviewer made their own [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30777590/revisions), that was extremely superficial (just capitalization changes, and removing 'thank you'). I would argue that if my edit is unacceptable, then this one should be as well. Is this a case of a reviewer trying to get 'editing' points? Is there any recourse for such a situation (other than having enough reputation as to not need edit approval)?

Comment: Users with 2K rep don't get editing points, they edit because they want to help. He for virtually no reward for that reject and edit. He obviously felt you editor was not correct

Comment: @psubsee2003 Regardless of reputation, you can be awarded badges for editing. Perhaps he wants to get the 'Copy Editor' badge?

Comment: @MuertoExcobito That user earned the Copy Editor badge in 2012.

Comment: Which is why i said "virtually" no reward.  There are badges from certain tasks, but it is a real stretch to say that you had a 1 single "good edit" rejected because the user is trying to get a badge (that he already has).

Comment: Irrespective of reward, why would a reviewer make an edit, than in all likelihood they would reject if they were reviewing it?

Comment: Why do you think he would reject it.  I am not in a position to debate your edit because you made changes to the actual question that I am not qualified to address.  It may have been good or it may not, but there was absolutely nothing wrong with the reviewers edit.  Cleaning up spelling, capitalization, formatting, and removing noise is what edits are designed to do.

Comment: I don't know why he would reject it. I made it, because I thought it was a good edit :). The reviewer has very minimal activity in the [c++] tag, so he probably also isn't qualified to know whether my edit was good or not. My contention is that he just rejects everything (as shown by his review history), and then makes edits, which he himself would reject if reviewing. While I understand that privileges are awarded based on reputation, it seems like an abuse of the system.

Comment: @s-l-barth thought his edit is better than yours and I also think so. I taged him may be he will response here.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito I was responding to your `in all likelihood they would reject if they were reviewing it?` comment.  You seem convinced that the reviewer's edit is bad.  I'm trying to say it is not bad.  Trying to compare the 2 is not the right question here.  If you really want to understand the situation, your question would be better asked "Why was my edit rejected" and stop worrying about the subsequent edit.

Comment: Having looked over the original, your suggestion and barth's edit, you seem to have inadvertently slightly but significantly changed the question. So, the rejection was proper. Actually, seeing your good answer there, and having read it too, I'm slightly puzzled why you edited it that way.

Comment: @Deduplicator The significant change in my edit was not inadvertent. Without my edit the question doesn't really make sense, as the NDK is GNU based.

Comment: So, the GNU ibstdc++ is the only option, no way to use a different standard library implementation? If you say so. That still changes the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had also rejected this edit, I've no real knowledge of Android NDK nor C++ but what I found "bad" in your edit is:

- It becomes harder to read than the original one.
- It change the question and conflict with the author intention.

Your edit is a correct question but it's a different one than the OP question in my point of view. OP aimed to get clarification of which implementation supports exceptions and what it can use if not using GNU's STL (and in this case aimed at Android NDK usage but the question is wider than just this point).